# Why are new dependencies not picked up by Play 2.3.4 project in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, sbt, playframework-2.3, typesafe-activator

I updated my project to include some dependencies with the following lines in `build.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies += "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.33"
libraryDependencies += "org.springframework" % "spring-jdbc" % "4.1.1.RELEASE"
```

`classes_managed` was added to the classpath, but the directory does not exist and the libs are not present.

I `clean`ed the project, removed all errors (including all references to the classes in the managed libs), `compile`, but still the directory and libs are missing.

SBT does not seem to want to download the libs... not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: The issue with classes_managed is not related to the sbt build dependencies, that was just because my project hadn't compiled after I cleaned it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Any dependency managed by sbt ends up in `~/.ivy2/cache` (it's [configurable](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Library-Management.html#Ivy+Home+Directory)).

When you declare a project's dependency with `libraryDependencies` you should execute `update` (explicitly) or any other command to build up your project assembly like `package` or `assembly` that is going to pull them down (via `update` implicitly).

One caveat might be that you may've changed `build.sbt` without `reload`ing a sbt session that makes the changes with no effect on the build. You should do `reload` to re-read the build definition or close sbt and start over.

A very helpful command to see what `libraryDependencies` are in use is `show libraryDependencies`. It's going to show you all the dependencies sbt knows about.

Once it's done, run `eclipse` command that prepares the files for the IDE. Do project reload in Eclipse and all should be fine.

It equally applies to sbt or [Typesafe Activator](https://typesafe.com/activator) (and partially IntelliJ IDEA).

Comment: Yes I could see the dependencies in `~/.ivy2/cache` after running `reload` and `update` thanks for pointing that out. One more thing I had to do after following those steps was to add the libs to the classpath (I was hoping typesafe activator would do this for me but seemingly not, at least not in eclipse), instead of doing it manually I simply ran the `eclipse` command again under the activator console. When I reloaded the project all was ok. Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad it's worked for you. That's the beauty of working with IDE - they rule the world differently (from sbt) so when sbt's happy, so could be IDE (but it's not certain all the time).